# About primitive roots.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, primitive-roots

> Assuming $6$ is a primitive root mod $p$ ( for some odd prime $p$) ( assuming this is possible) then could $p$ have another distinct primitive root $n$ (such that $1 \lt n \lt (p-1)$) where $(6,n) = 1$?

Comment: I noticed if c is a primitive root mod p , c = (a b) then let $(c^A)\equiv(a)\pmod{p}$ and $(c^B)\equiv(b)\pmod{p}$ , then A + B = p

Answer (score 2):

Modulo 17, there are [8](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=primitive+roots+mod+17) primitive roots, including 6, 10, 12, 14.

Comment: Being odd or even isn't even really a valid concept modulo an odd number. For example, 20, 22, 24, and 28 are also primmitive roots modulo 17 (as are 40, 44, ...). It certainly has no bearing on whether a number is a primitive root (mod $p$) or not.

Comment: IF n is a least residue you can certainly say it's odd or even.  Notice I said 1 < n < (p-1).

Comment: Are primitive roots usually square-free?

Comment: What I should say , are primitive roots usually a product of a quadratic residue ( not congruent to 1) and one or more distinct primes all in the same mod m ,say?

Comment: The square-free quality can be applied to congruences. If N = (v^2) w mod m where v is not = 1 mod m and w is the product of distinct primes then say N is not square-free relative to mod m. So if R is not in this form '(v^2) w mod m' then R is square free relative to m. Is this feasible?